# input time на js обьект date

Tags: javascript

У меня есть инпуты типа тайм как можно их сравнивать или преобразить в обьекта date

Comment: сравнить можно как строки. `'20:00'.localeCompare('20:30')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объект `Date` кроме времени, содержит еще и дату. И на основании одного времени вы объект `Date` не сконструируете. Но если добавить какую-то дату (например текущую), то можно просто вызвать конструктор

```js
new Date(curDate + " " + input.value);
```

```js
document.getElementById("get").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const timeStr = document.getElementById("time").value;
  console.log(timeStr);
  const date = new Date(new Date().toDateString() + " " + timeStr);
  console.log(date.toString());
})
```

```html
<input id="time" type="time"/>
<input id="get" type="button" value="Get Time"/>
```